# ls | wc using C doesn't work

Tags: c, pipe

I'have written a C program which uses multiple piping to simulate shell. The problem is I can run most of the commands like `ls | cat` etc, but I'm unable to use `ls | wc`. Is there any case when `wc` doesn't work?

```
int pipefd[4]; 
int p1 = pipe(pipefd);          // Open pipe 1
int p2 = pipe(pipefd + 2);      // Open pipe 2

pid_t pid;

for(i = 0; i < n_commands; i++)
{
    fflush(stdout);
    pid = fork();

    if(pid == 0)
    {
        int command_no = i;
        int prev_pipe = ((command_no - 1) % 2) * 2;
        int current_pipe = (command_no % 2) * 2;

        // If current command is the first command, close the
        // read end, else read from the last command's pipe
        if(command_no == 0)
        {
            close(pipefd[0]);
        }
        else
        {
            dup2(pipefd[prev_pipe], 0);
            close(pipefd[current_pipe]);
        }

        // If current command is the last command, close the
        // write end, else write to the pipe
        if(command_no == n_commands - 1)
        {
            close(pipefd[current_pipe + 1]);
        }
        else
        {
            dup2(pipefd[current_pipe + 1], 1);
        }

        int p = execvp(tokens[cmd_pos[command_no]], tokens + cmd_pos[command_no]);

        close(pipefd[current_pipe]);
        close(pipefd[prev_pipe]);
        close(pipefd[prev_pipe + 1]);
        close(pipefd[current_pipe + 1]);

        _exit(0);
    }
}
```

It seems that the programs from `/usr/bin` are not being executed if they are not the first command in the pipeline.

Comment: You are encountering this problem when you try to invoke this command from inside your "shell" C program? What happens?

Comment: Yes, in the C program. Nothing happens, and `execvp()` doesn't return any error.

Comment: Can you show some code ?

Comment: Odd .. I assume you've tried other commands involving pipes? Do those work? What if you try `ls` by itself? Or if you do something like `cat somefile | wc` .. just trying to think of some way to narrow down the problem.

Comment: Please post the smallest amount of source that would reproduce this problem. Like a minimal C program that would demonstrate this problem. Thanks.

Comment: @Levon, yep I tried that.. didn't work.

Comment: Ok then, I agree with the others, try to provide some code .. ideally something along the lines of [this -ie small, self-contained and compilable](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Here is the code for multiple piping: http://pastebin.com/KW1EPAX9. It's a bit complicated.

Comment: It seems that programs in `/usr/bin` are not working.

Comment: @green7: please just paste the code in the question and don't like to pastebins. This one, for example, I can't access for some reason.

Comment: @green7: I've just assembled a quick example of your code and I think I see the output of the first command. My guess then would be that you are connecting the pipes somehow wrong, or I am using it wrong :P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a very simple program created from your code — guessing how pipes might be created and simplifying the command `argv` handling a bit:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static char *argv_ls[] = { "ls", 0 };
static char *argv_wc[] = { "wc", 0 };
static char **cmds[]   = { argv_ls, argv_wc };

int main(void)
{
    int n_commands = 2;
    int pipefd[2];

    pipe(&pipefd[0]);   // Error check!

    fflush(stdout);
    for (int i = 0; i < n_commands; i++)
    {
        int pid = fork();

        if (pid == 0)
        {
            int command_no = i;
            int prev_pipe = ((command_no - 1) % 2) * 2;
            int current_pipe = (command_no % 2) * 2;
            printf("cmd %d: prev pipe %d, curr pipe %d\n", i, prev_pipe, current_pipe);
            fflush(stdout);

            // If current command is the first command, close the
            // read end, else read from the last command's pipe
            if (command_no == 0)
            {
                close(pipefd[0]);
            }
            else
            {
                dup2(pipefd[prev_pipe], 0);
                close(pipefd[current_pipe]);  // Line 40
            }

            // If current command is the last command, close the
            // write end, else write to the pipe
            if (command_no == n_commands - 1)
                close(pipefd[current_pipe + 1]);  // Line 46
            else
                dup2(pipefd[current_pipe + 1], 1);

            execvp(cmds[i][0], cmds[i]);
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to exec: %s (%d: %s)\n", cmds[i][0], errno, strerror(errno));
            _exit(1);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When GCC 4.7.1 (on Mac OS X 10.7.4) compiles it, it warns:

```
pipes-12133858.c: In function ‘main’:
pipes-12133858.c:40:22: warning: array subscript is above array bounds [-Warray-bounds]
pipes-12133858.c:46:22: warning: array subscript is above array bounds [-Warray-bounds]
```

When I run it, I get the output:

```
Isis JL: pipes-12133858
cmd 0: prev pipe -2, curr pipe 0
cmd 1: prev pipe 0, curr pipe 2
Isis JL: wc: stdin: read: Bad file descriptor
```

Since the parent in the code does not wait for the children to finish, the prompt appears before the error message from `wc`, but the diagnostic numbers printed show that there are all sorts of problems (and the compiler was able to spot some of the problems).

Note that there is no need to check the return value from any of the `exec*()` family of functions.  If they are successful, they do not return; if they return, they failed.  There was also no need for the closes before calling `_exit(0);` since the system will close them anyway.  Also, when you fail to exec something, it is courteous to print a message indicating what you failed to execute and to exit with a non-zero exit status.

So, as [Michał Górny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/165333/michal-gorny) says, a major part of your problem is that your pipe handling code is at least mysterious because you didn't show it and probably erroneous.

I'm also tolerably sure you don't have enough `close()` calls in your code.  As a guideline, in each process that has pipes open in it that is going to be part of a pipeline, all the file descriptors returned by the `pipe()` system call should be closed before any given child process uses an `exec*()` function.  Not closing pipes can lead to processes hanging because the write end of a pipe is open.  If the process that has the write end open is the process that's trying to read from the read end of the pipe, then it isn't going to find any data to read.

Comment: There is some problem in the line `int command_no = i`. Do you know how can I access `i`? (without using shared memory)

Comment: @green7: There is?  The value of `i` in the parent and the child are the same.  On the first iteration, the value of `i` and hence `command_no` is 0; `(0 - 1) % 2` is `-1`, and `2 * -1` is `-2` as in the printed values.  Etc.  Maybe you were unaware that the modulus of a negative number and a positive number is negative or zero?

Comment: Oh, it's right. :) Also, the value of `prev_pipe` doesn't matter in the first iteration, as there is code which checks if the command is the first command. Also, there are two pipes: `pipefd[0, 1]` and `pipefd[2,3]`. First command writes in `current_pipe+1 = 1`, next command reads from `prev_pipe = 0`, and writes to either `stdout` or `current_pipe+1 = 3`.

Comment: Why do you have two pipes for `ls | wc`?

Comment: I'm trying to implement a generalized version, for cases when there are more than 1 pipe.

Comment: But the generalized version should be specialized enough to create N-1 pipes for N commands; when there are N=2 commands, you only need N-1 = 1 pipes, don't you?  How many pipe symbols did you type on the command line?

Comment: Isn't it true that I can create only two pipes and have `ls | cat | wc` work?

Comment: Yes, if you have a three part pipeline, you need two separate pipes; if you have a two part pipeline like `ls | wc`, you need just one pipe.  Should we move to chat?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15833/discussion-between-jonathan-leffler-and-green7)

Answer (score 1):

You are connecting the pipes incorrectly.

This logic:

```
int prev_pipe = ((command_no - 1) % 2) * 2;
int current_pipe = (command_no % 2) * 2;
```

doesn't work — the result of modulo will always be `0` or `1`, so `prev_pipe` and `current_pipe` will be either `0` or `2`...

Well, unless I'm missing some hidden concept because you didn't paste any code creating the pipes.

Comment: I think the general idea is that if you have N commands, there will be N-1 pipes created in a single array of integers: `int pipefd[2*MAX_PIPELINE]; for (int i = 0; i < N-1; i++) if (pipe(&pipefd[2*i]]) != 0) ...report error...;`  I'm suspicious that in general there are not enough closes in the code; that's a common source of trouble.  However, in this example, there should only be one pipe, which limits the possibilities for damage.  Generally, by the time you're done connecting pipes to stdin and stdout, there should be no file descriptors from `pipe()` left open.

Comment: As I said, it supports multiple piping. I've declared two pipes `pipefd[0,1]` and `pipefd[2,3]`, which will take care of communication, no matter how many pipes are there.