# how to execute ls | wc -w using pipes?

Tags: c, linux, terminal, pipe, wc

i am trying to create a shell program to execute piped command. When i call ls from forked child & wc from parent it works fine. but if i call wc also from forked child parent keeps on waiting (i don't know why this is happening).

```
void execPiped(char** Args,char** pipedArgs)
{
    int pfds[2];
    pipe(pfds);
    pid_t pid1 = fork();
    if (pid1 == -1)
    {
        printf("\nFailed forking child..");
        return;
    }
    else if (pid1 == 0) //CHILD 1 EXECUTING
    {
        close(1);       //close STDOUT
        dup(pfds[1]);   //set pfds as STDOUT
        close(pfds[0]); //we don't need this
        if (execvp(Args[0], Args) < 0)
        {
            printf("\nCould not execute command..");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    else {
        pid_t pid2 = fork();
        if (pid2 == -1)
        {
            printf("\nFailed forking child..");
            return;
        }
        else if (pid2 == 0) //CHILD 2 EXECUTING
        {
            close(0);       //close STDIN
            dup(pfds[0]);   //set pfds as STDIN
            close(pfds[1]); //we don't need this
            if (execvp(pipedArgs[0], pipedArgs) < 0)
            {
                printf("\nCould not execute command..");
                exit(1);
            }
        }
        else {  //Parent Executing
            //Wating for Children to exit
            wait(NULL);
            wait(NULL);
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: You aren't closing enough file descriptors in the child. **Rule of thumb**: If you [`dup2()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html) one end of a pipe to standard input or standard output, close both of the original file descriptors from `pipe()` as soon as possible. In particular, that means before using any of the [`exec*()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execvp.html) family of functions. The rule also applies with either `dup()` or [`fcntl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fcntl.html) with `F_DUPFD`.

Comment: The parent process also needs to close both ends of the pipe.  Otherwise, `wc` will never get an EOF indication.

Comment: Note that error messages should be reported on standard error, not standard output.  Also, please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  We don't have the calling context for the function shown.  You should hard-wire the data structures passed to the function, but we should be able to compile and run the program and see the problem you see — which means you need to describe the expected and actual outputs (but using a newly created almost empty directory probably helps in this case).

Comment: Amongst others, see [`ls | wc` using C doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12133858).

Comment: ok i will try this